# Is there any way to filter UIImagePickerController camera input?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uiimagepickercontroller, filtering

I mean, I need to implement some camera like socialcam or viddy that capable to use filters. I have made some class that use as composition an UIImagePickerController class, I have customized it's cameraOverlayView and now I don't know how to filter picker's camera input, then show picker preview filtered and capture it. Do I need to implement my own camera based on GPUImage examples instead?

Comment: I would go with `GPUImage` since its faster.

Comment: I mean, how to combine GPUImage and picker.

Comment: You can't, use `GPUImageStillCamera`. See the documentation https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage